# Android Fragment refresh doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to sort my picture list in a GridView which is on a seperate fragment.
The issue is when I remove old fragment and add new fragment the old one stil prevails and the new one prints top of it.
this is how I refresh the View.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("sort", sort);

    android.support.v4.app.Fragment frg = new MainActivityFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment currentFrg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(currentFrg);
    frg.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.add(R.id.fragment, frg).commit();
```

Please give me some hint regarding this.

this is the Fragment class

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private MovieAdaptor movieAdaptor;

GridView gridView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

   ImageView iconView = (ImageView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);

   FetchMovieTask task = new FetchMovieTask();
    String sort = "";
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        sort = bundle.getString("sort", "popularity.desc");
    }

    try {
        movieAdaptor    = new MovieAdaptor(this.getActivity(), (List<Movie>) task.execute(sort).get() );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    if(movieAdaptor != null){

        Log.e("MOVIE_DATA", "movieAdaptor IS NOT NULL ");
        gridView.setAdapter(movieAdaptor);

    }else {
        Log.e("MOVIE_DATA", "movieAdaptor IS NULL");
    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

and in MainActivity when the option menu changes this transaction calls;
this is the regarding code;

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    String sort = "";

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_sort_rating) {
        sort = "vote_average.desc";

    }

    if(id == R.id.action_sort_popularity){
        sort = "popularity.desc";

    }

    if(id == R.id.action_sort_release_date){
        sort = "release_date.desc";

    }

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("sort", sort);
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment frg = new MainActivityFragment();
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    frg.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment, frg).commit();



    return  true;

    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

this is my fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$MainActivityFragment">


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
   >

</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
      android:name="com.alpha0.popular_movies_app.MainActivityFragment"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as @Guillaume Imbert pointed out, your problem is `fragment` tag. Replce the `fragment` tag with a `RelativeLayout`, and inside the relative layout have a `FrameLayout` with id=fragment. Then dynamically in the activity use the `TransactionManager` to set the `Fragment`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: @rolde wow you solution works perfectly. I appreciate your advice. I wouldn't know how to get through this if wasn't for you. thanks.

Comment: Actually the RelativeLayout around the FrameLout should be removed, to suppress a layout pass. You can just use directly the FrameLayout

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("sort", sort);
android.support.v4.app.Fragment frg = new MainActivityFragment();
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
frg.setArguments(bundle);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, frg).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks I think this solution will work. Let me try it.

Comment: Nada :( same scenario happens. I will post my fragment as well.

Comment: Show the class that calls this transaction, you may not pass in the block of code.

Comment: Ok I think your problem is in your xml. I bet you have a layout with I'd R.id.fragment, and inside it a tag <fragment />. Is that it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. But there is no fragment tag.

Comment: Can you post your layout were you use the id "fragment"?

Comment: oops!. I think You are correct. I will post my activity_main.xml as well.